# How to align newline in java?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to align the very long text?

For example of this code:

```
System.out.println("\tHi this is a very long string to test the automated newline but I want to have the newline to be tab indented too.");
```

Instead of having below

```
    Hi this is a very long string to test the automated newline but I want to 
have the newline to be tab indented too.
```

I want this

```
    Hi this is a very long string to test the automated newline but I want to 
    have the newline to be tab indented too.
```

So, I want the newline to be aligned with the first sentence. Is there any library exist out there or default String Java method?

Comment: `\t` is a tab, but you should probably look into why your first line is aligned like that in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I edited my question...

Answer (score 1):

Use ( "\t" + "Hi, this is newline") in the print statement

Answer (score 1):

Could you show us the code you're using? You would probably want \t on both lines if you want them both aligned and tabbed.

Comment: This isn't technically possible, seeing as the string will be displayed differently based on how wide your console is. If you pick a specific point at which you want the line to split, you can put in a newline and tab, but again if the console is shrunk to be less wide than your predetermined line length, it will be off again.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. The width of the console can vary from execution to execution, and Java simply doesn't make that information available. However, you can probably assume that the minimum is 80 characters and just wrap it manually at 80 characters. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055430/).

Comment: I am still seeing this as option because it may not possible to use that since i can't never know the wrapLength but I still vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in method in the JDK for doing this.

The best solution I'm aware of is to use [`WordUtils.wrap(String str, int wrapLength, String newLineStr, boolean wrapLongWords)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#wrap%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) which is part of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

This method allows you to specify the number of columns at which to wrap as well as your newline character.  You could use `\n\t` as your newline which should wrap the line and then tab indent the next line as you've asked.

Example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String longString = "\tThe quick brown fox jumps over the fence";
        System.out.println(WordUtils.wrap(longString, 10, "\n\t", false));
    }

}
```

**-- Edit --**

The Commons Lang library might be too large to include with an Android application.  However, the source code for `WordUtils.wrap(...)` is readily available so you could always create your own stripped-down version of `WordUtils`.

Comment: I am still seeing this as option because it may not possible to use that since i can't never know the wrapLength but I still vote up your answer.

Comment: You might be able to work out the number of columns on the current display (wrapLength) if  you know the screen resolution and font.  The [Measuring Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) tutorial explains how this is done with Java 2D

Comment: Can't put the number statically because my string width can be vary from time to time :D

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way of achieving word-wrapping through `String` API. You would have to come up with a utility method of your own. Here's a simple implementation that wraps the `String` input at the specified `lineSize`.

```
void printWordWrapped(String string, int lineSize) {
    int len = (len = string.length()) > lineSize ? lineSize : len;
    do {
        System.out.printf("\t%s\n", string.substring(0, len).trim());
        string = string.substring(len);
        len = (len = string.length()) > lineSize ? lineSize : len;
    } while (len > 0);
}

printWordWrapped("Hi this is a short string.", 30);
System.out.println();
printWordWrapped("Hi this is a very long string to test " +
                 "the automated newline but I want to have " + 
                 "the newline to be tab indented too.", 30);
```

***Output** :*

```
    Hi this is a short string.

    Hi this is a very long string
    to test the automated newline
    but I want to have the newline
    to be tab indented too.
```

Comment: Yes I agree there is no way to do it. However, I can't use this way because I can never know the length of the string before goes to newline :(

Comment: @Rendy, you don't have to know the length. Just pick one lineSize constant consistently. 30 was used just for the demo. Standard line wrap size is 80 used in e-mails for example.

Comment: Can't put the number statically because my string width can be vary from time to time :D

Comment: It's not the string length you have to know, it's the length of the view and it's always known somehow. In HTML it could be the width of the `<textarea>` or like for emails, width of content `<div>` usually about 80. For a desktop application like notepad it would be the number of columns calculated from the current size of the window. Similarly, in Android there would be a way to know the current width of a `TextView` which is what should decide the `lineSize` here. Again, the length of the string doesn't matter and does **not** need to be known beforehand.