# Split a string in a list of padded strings?

Tags: java, string

I want to pad a string on a certain end margin and I want each pad to be a string in a list.

What I tried:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
for (String splits : Splitter.fixedLength(32).split(tip)) lines.add(splits);
for (String line : lines) // stuff here per line
```

Problem here is it cuts the words:

[image: "manipulation" was cut off]

The word manipulation gets cut off, I want it to jump to the next line instead.

Let's say I have this string:

String example = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam aliquid deleniti officiis eu."

So after running that string through some function, it'd return a list with the following:

```
lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, nam
aliquid deleniti
officiis eu.
```

Notice, I'm not splitting every nth character! That's done with guava's Splitter. I want to pad everything to a certain end margin and have all the pads go into a string list.

Guava has a Strings.something that does this but doesn't return a list

How can I split the pads into a list? I was thinking about using guava's Strings.something method to do the pad and then split that string every \n or something.

Comment: You are probably too new on SO to know that people here like to see efforts from people asking to solve their problems. What have you tried so far?

Comment: From your current position `c`, move `n` characters forwards. Move backwards until you find a space (or a word break or whatever). Print the substring between `c` and the current position. Repeat.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin updated post

Comment: You might also want to [read this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055430/java-code-for-wrapping-text-lines-to-a-max-line-width) check out the second answer and have a look into [apache commons Word util's warp mathod](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
public static ArrayList<String> padString(String string, int stringSize) {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : WordUtils.wrap(string, stringSize).split("\n")) lines.add(line.trim());
    return lines;
}
```